# Windows 10 changes keyboard layout on shutdown / sleep

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout

In Windows 10 I use a bunch of different keyboard layouts because the machines and keyboards were bought in different countries. I have read all those questions about seemingly random or automatic changes, e.g. on a keyboard shortcut, and all fixes, e.g. regedit or adding and removing a layout. However, nothing was able to fix this specific issue I have: on my machine (Lenovo T490 [swiss german layout] with docking and separate bluetooth dongle for old MX5000 keyboard mouse combo [german layout]), every restart of power-off reverts the keyboard layout to swiss german.

How do I turn this off?

Comment: Try in *Settings > Devices > Typing > Advanced keyboard settings* to set "Override for default input method" to your preferred layout.

Comment: If you are not using Schwyzerdütsch, then you can remove that language: https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/2-ways-to-delete-language-on-windows-10.html